# How many transactions can cardano-wallet perform per minute?

Tags: wallet, yoroi

Let's say I automate the process to send 5 ADA (or 1 NFT) to 100 wallets.

If I'd do this with `Yoroi` it would take a lot of time and manual work.

If I'd do this with `cardano-wallet` there is no manual work...but how much time would this take?

So how many transactions can `cardano-wallet` perform *at once* or *per minute*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it really depends on how much UTxO's you have currently in your wallet. If you use one UTxO per transaction then you can send out multiple transactions in parallel.

Also you can increase output buy making multiple outputs per transaction, if your case is to send funds as quickly as possible.

As far as the real metric goes I don't think it can be easily calculated. But if it means anything for you apparently Cardano currently [has 250TPS on layer 1 and will increase to about 1000 after Hydra](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/nufvg0/cardano_tps_after_alonzo/).